# Why are document/window heights and scrollTop() values different in mobile browsers, using jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery, scroll

I'm using a scroll event (jQuery) to load more items once the bottom of a page is reached:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == ($(document).height() - $(window).height())) {
        // Load more items
    }
}
```

And it works perfect on my desktop, but doesn't do anything in mobile browsers because the values do not match when at the bottom of the page. For example `$(window).scrollTop() == 1056` but `( $(document).height() - $(window).height() ) == 1152` when at the bottom of a page in any mobile browser (I used Android). Not sure if it has anything to do with it but apparently in mobile browsers, the values are floats with as many as 10 decimal points, although when at the bottom of a page the values are whole numbers after all.

Resizing the desktop browser to a mobile screen size does **not** reproduce this issue so it is definitely a mobile browser thing. I'm currently using the ancient jQuery 2.1.1 but if any newer version has a working solution to this problem, I might try that.

Why are these values different on mobile browsers and how do I make my script work in mobile browsers as well using jQuery / JavaScript?

Comment: Use `Math.round()` to discard the fractions.

Comment: what version of jQuery?

Comment: jQuery version is 2.1.1

Comment: There have been a LOT of changes since 2.1.1; including some security fixes which you SHOULD get perhaps IMHO.   I don't remember for sure but my guess is 2.1.1 is over 10 years old.. OK, May 2014 so not quite 10 yet.

Comment: What jQuery version does have a solid solution to the issue described above? I read using `noConflict()` allows for multiple versions to co-exist. Might do that until all functions have been updated. The project I'm working on is pretty outdated as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by getting the `window.innerHeight` instead of the `$(window).height()` property. To account for the float values that mobile browsers produce for `.scrollTop()` I used `Math.round()` to round the number to the nearest whole number. `Math.floor()` produces minor differences when the values become large enough causing the scroll event to not be registered.

My script now looks as follows:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if (Math.round($(window).scrollTop()) == ($(document).height() - window.innerHeight)) {
        // Load more items
    }
}
```

and works for both mobile and desktop browsers.